# Adapt apacite citation style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apacite

I'm using Bibtex together with the apacite package and apacite citation style.
Instead of the citation style

> (Goossens, Mittelbach, & Samarin, 1994, 14)

...I need...

> (**M.** Goossens, **F.** Mittelbach, & **A.** Samarin, 1994, **p.**
> 14)

Is it possible to achieve this in any way?
Maybe even without adding **p.** to all `\cite[]{}` commands as e.g. `\cite[p. 14]{Goossens}` ?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  year      = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite[14]{Goossens}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi :) Have you already had success in adapting the style? I am facing a somewhat similar issue. Best
F

Comment: This is not likely to be possible using `apacite`. Here's a solution using `biblatex`, however. [mandatory initials in citations with biblatex authoryear-icomp](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/439857)